# Is it possible to design an Infopath template that will have only one set of fields which can be duplicated when using the Formfiller?

Tags: 2010, infopath, design

I am designing a form in Infopath to collect information from the staff members in my department.  These will be standard lists of project experience based on a table format with start and end dates, project name, duties, etc.  However, since they have different levels of experience, some may only need to complete e.g. 2 of the tables where others might need to complete as many as ten.

I'd like to only design one table and then have the ability to enable the user when using Formfiller to populate as many of these tables as his/her experience requires.  How would I get that result and then still have different binding fields?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What is FormFiller? Are you referring to InfoPath Filler versus InfoPath Designer? This is not a SharePoint specific question.

It looks like you use InfoPath to design a form that will be filled in by users using InfoPath Filler. Regardless of whether you use a InfoPath List form or an InfoPath Browser form for SharePoint, or an InfoPath form that will be presented in InfoPath Filler, the steps will be the same:

In the first part of the form, create controls where the user selects their level of experience.

Below that you can create several sections in the form. You can format these sections to be hidden. To do that, you select the section and add a formatting rule for the section. Set the condition of the formatting rule so that it will be hidden UNLESS one of the key controls in the top of the form has a specific value.

This is the standard procedure to show/hide parts of a form, be it in IP Filler, browser or list forms.

If you need more detail on how to achieve this, please provide more details about your form.